# update value in cart

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am developing shopping cart application in MVC 4 where I need to update the amount on changing the cart quantity.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.ProductId</td>
        <td>@item.Product.ProductName</td>
        <td id="PriceBx">@item.Product.UnitPrice</td>

        <td id="QtyBx" oninput="calculate()">@Html.TextBox("QuantityBox", item.Quantity, new { style = "width:50px" })</td>
        <td id="result">@String.Format("{0:c}", Convert.ToDouble(item.Quantity) * Convert.ToDouble(item.Product.UnitPrice))</td>

    </tr>
}
```

In this I need to update the **total** when the value in **QuantityBox** is changed.

I tried using Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculate()
{

    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('QtyBx').value;
    var myBox2 = document.getElementById('PriceBx').value;
    var result = document.getElementById('result');
    var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
    result.innerHTML = myResult;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generating multiple elements using a `foreach` then using `id` attribute for elements inside it is never a good idea because element `id` has to be unique per HTML page.

Try to append the product-id to the element id:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.ProductId</td>
        <td>@item.Product.ProductName</td>
        <td id="PriceBx@(item.ProductId)">@item.Product.UnitPrice</td>

        <td id="QtyBx@(item.ProductId)" oninput="calculate(@(item.ProductId))">@Html.TextBox("QuantityBox", item.Quantity, new { style = "width:50px" })</td>
        <td id="result@(item.ProductId)">@String.Format("{0:c}", Convert.ToDouble(item.Quantity) * Convert.ToDouble(item.Product.UnitPrice))</td>

    </tr>
}
```

And in your Javascript:

```
function calculate(itemId)
{
    var myBox1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('QtyBx' + itemId).value, 10);
    var myBox2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('PriceBx' + itemId).value);
    var result = document.getElementById('result' + itemId);
    var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;

    result.innerHTML = myResult;
}
```

(I took the liberty to explicitly convert the values of your inputs to `int` and `float` respectively)

Answer (score 1):

first of all, some remarks:

- you're using an `id` in your HTML and you're repeating it through your `Model`, this breaks the rule that one page should have unique id's
- You're not using any javascript framework, though pure javascript is a way to accomplish what you need, but in the future you might have some cross-broser issues when performing more advance tasks
- you have an `onInput` in your `td`, but it should be in the checkbox it self

you can easily use your own textbox markup:

```
<td id="QtyBx" oninput="calculate()">
    @Html.TextBox("QuantityBox", item.Quantity, new { style = "width:50px" })
</td>
<td id="result">
   ...
</td>
```

change to:

```
<td class="quantity">
    <input type="number" id="QuantityBox_@item.Product.ProductId" 
           value="@item.Quantity" 
           data-unitprice="@item.Product.UnitPrice"
           data-productid="@item.Product.ProductId"
           onchange="calculate(this)" />
</td>
```

...

and, using jQuery (to handle the `data-` easier) should be something like:

```
function calculate(elm) {
  var chk = $(elm),                // the checkbox
      vlu = chk.val(),             // the current qty value
      pid = chk.data("productid"), // product id
      unt = chk.data("unitprice"), // unit price
      res = $(".result_" + pid),   // the result for this product
      tot = vlu * unt;             // total

  res.text("$" + tot);             // write the value
}
```

a live example: https://jsbin.com/gafaja/edit?html,js,output

---

if you still wanna learn/do it in plain javascript:

```
function calculate(elm) {
  var vlu = elm.value,           // the current qty value
      pid = elm.getAttribute("data-productid"), // product id
      unt = elm.getAttribute("data-unitprice"), // unit price
      res = document.getElementsByClassName("result_" + pid),   // the result for this product
      tot = vlu * unt;             // total

  res[0].innerHTML = "$" + tot; // write the value
}
```

one more thing...

don't add `style` to the elements, just add a stylesheet as:

```
<style>
  .quantity input { width:50px; }
</style>
```